# Why can't I stream mkv from my Debian server running ffserver?

Tags: linux, video-streaming, matroska

I've got a Debian Linux server with a bunch of mkv files that I would like to play from anywhere without directly downloading the files. In other words, I would like to stream them.

I've tried using ffmpeg's ffserver, but I couldn't get it to work. The problem was that it wouldn't show the video, and the stream would cut off after about 18 seconds. This was the config I used for ffserver for that experiment:

```
Port 5004
BindAddress 10.0.0.1
MaxHTTPConnections 2000
MaxClients 1000
MaxBandwidth 1000
CustomLog -
NoDaemon

<Stream stream.mkv>
        Format h264
        File "clip.mkv"

        VideoCodec libx264
        VideoFrameRate 30
        VideoBitRate 512
        VideoSize 320x240
        AVOptionVideo crf 23
        AVOptionVideo preset medium
        # for more info on crf/preset options, type: x264 --help
        AVOptionVideo flags +global_header

        AudioCodec aac
        Strict -2
        AudioBitRate 128
        AudioChannels 2
        AudioSampleRate 44100
        AVOptionAudio flags +global_header
</Stream>
```

How can I rectify this issue?

Comment: to where and to what clients are you wanting to stream? If you are just talking about lan connections, I use samba for the same affect with no particular configuration for video "streaming". just go to the share, and play the file. the file's contents are streamed to ram and are discarded when no longer needed, but not cache to disk.

Comment: Frank Thomas: I was thinking about streaming to my iPad over WiFi, and the server is remote but it's got good upload and download. For now I've just been testing on Windows 8 with MPC-HC by taking the stream link and opening that as a file. I'll look into samba.